# Estimating the largest radius making each ball in a finite metric space into a tree

Tags: graph-theory, mg.metric-geometry, metric-spaces, trees

**Motivation:**
Let $n$ be a positive integer and $(X,d)$ be an $n$-point metric space.  Clearly, $(X,d)$ need not be a metric tree *(e.g. take for example the discrete metric on $\{0,1,2\}$*.

Conversely, consider the *non-negative integer* radius $r:= \lfloor \frac{\min_{x,y\in X;\,x\neq y}\,d(x,y)}{2}\rfloor$.  Then, $r$ is such that:
$$
\mbox{for every $x\in X$ $(Ball_d(x,r),d)$ is a metric tree}
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\boldsymbol{(1)}.
$$
By a [metric tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tree) I mean a metric space $(X,d)$ which is isometric to some weighted tree with graph geodesic distance.

---

**Question:**
Are there classes of (possibly random) graphs for which the largest possible *integer* $r$ satisfying **(1)** can be estimated (with high probability)?

*I'm expecting that the statement will have something to do with the ration of the valency to number of vertices...*

**Non-triviality:**
For instance, if $(X_1,d_1),\dots,(X_k,d_k)$ are metric trees each with $n$-points, then their "disjoint union" $X:=\sqcup_{i=1}^k X_i$ with metric
$$
d(x,y):= 
\begin{cases}
d_i(x,y) &: x,y\in X_i\\
L &: (\not\exists I)\, x,y\in X_i,
\end{cases}
$$
where $L:=2\lceil\max_{i=1,\dots,k}\,\operatorname{diam}(X_k)\rceil$, must have $r\approx L/2$.